# SDN4 inconsistient exceptions during database deadlock

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am testing my SDN4 based web service and during some specific performance tests I noticed that database deadlocks happen. I decided to make my application "deadlock proof", by catching appropriate exception and trying several more times. I used org.neo4j.kernel.DeadlockDetectedException, but putting this into catch did not work, so I simply put java.lang.Exception to catch anything. My results are like this:

With embedded database e.toString() gives:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.DeadlockDetectedException: LockClient[136] can't wait on resource RWLock[NODE(24437), hash=1741255175] since => LockClient[136] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(24422), hash=592554821] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[133] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(24437), hash=1741255175]
```

With standalone database e.toString() gives:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: Could not parse response; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ResultProcessingException: Could not parse response
```

Especially second case gives very generic exception. Catching this I could not be sure that it is really deadlock or something else. Only using wireshark, I was able to see that database response was really "deadlock". First one also looks strange, because DeadlockDetectedException is inside RuntimeException, so I was not able to catch it. Moreover both situations are inconsistient. Is this an expected behaviour?

Comment: We're aware of this problem, and actively investigating. We'll post an answer here as soon as we have a resolution.